# Android streaming with MediaCodec and VirtualDisplay, client disconnects

Tags: android, video-streaming, screen, android-mediacodec

I am working on an app that records the screen of my Android device and streams it over rtsp to another client. I am using VirtualDisplay and MediaCodec for this.

I have an issue that I don't know how to solve. When I start streaming, the client doesn't receive anything until the screen changes. I guess it makes sense, the buffer contains nothing, so nothing is sent to client. The code for that is this:

```
MediaCodec buildMediaCodec() throws IOException {
    MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);

    // Set some required properties. The media codec may fail if these aren't defined.
   format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
   format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
   format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
   format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1); // 1 seconds between I-frames

   // Create a MediaCodec encoder and configure it. Get a Surface we can use for recording into.
   MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
   mediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
   return mediaCodec;
}

// This is passed to buildVirtualDisplay(), and I get it from calling buildMediaCodec()
Surface mediaCodecSurface = mMediaCodec.createInputSurface();

VirtualDisplay buildVirtualDisplay(MediaProjection mediaProjection, Surface mediaCodecSurface, DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
   if (mediaProjection == null || mediaCodecSurface == null || displayMetrics == null) {
      throw new InvalidParameterException("MediaProjection, Surface and DisplayMetrics are mandatory");
   }
   return mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("Recording Display", VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT, SCREEN_DPI, 0 /* flags */, mediaCodecSurface, null /* callback */, null /* handler */);
}

...

mIndex = mMediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, 500000);
if (mIndex >= 0) {
    mBuffer = mMediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(mIndex);
    if (mBuffer == null) {
       throw new RuntimeException("couldn't fetch buffer at index " + mIndex);
    }
    mBuffer.position(0);
    break;
 } else if (mIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
    mMediaFormat = mMediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
    Log.i(TAG, mMediaFormat.toString());
 } else if (mIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
    Log.v(TAG, "No buffer available...");
 } else {
     Log.e(TAG, "Message: " + mIndex);
 }
```

In the logs I can see No buffer available... one after another. In the moment that the screen changes it stops.

The problem is when I stop interacting with the phone. The screen is not refreshed as nothing is changing, so I keep getting MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER. After 10 seconds or so, the client disconnects. I guess that it doesn't receive anything so it just shuts down the connection.

I also observed, that the longer I wait at the beginning the bigger is the delay between the server and client devices.

If I put a progress bar everything is ok, it seems that the screen is re-rendered so the buffer contains data to be sent.

I have looked for info about this problem. Any suggestion of what I might do to prevent this from happening? Should I used another Surface between MediaCodec and VirtualDisplay and try to "force" the rendering?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that client disconnects after not receiving data for at least 10 seconds. I try KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER from MediaFormat to prevent this, but so far no luck.

Comment: No, I kind of hacked it. I show an icon on the status bar. This icon is animated. I have a drawable with two images, these two images are the same, so the user doesn't see anything changing. But for Android it has to "repaint" that part, so it keeps generating frames.

Comment: Any update on this Antonio? Or was the hack sufficient for what you needed? I'm dealing with the same thing and trying to determine how to solve it. It's strange that the Android team hasn't addressed this at all.

Comment: The hack was kind of enough. The issue I found so far is that some phones don't use the icon I provide in the status bar, but the app icon. So that means that this issue happens in those devices.